# Symlink MongoDB ObjectID to Mysql mongoId attribute(FK)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

Not being able to store MongoDB auto-generated Object ID to a mysql table attribute mongo_id(FK)

I have already used https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb , tested the link between mysql ORM and MongoDB ODM/ORM using tinker and HybridRelations Trait from the package, but cannot auto-symlink the self-generated MongoDB ObjectID to a mysql table attribute mongo_id used as a Foreign Key. I have to manually copy that Object ID to the mysql table to test the relation/link between mysql and mongodb ORM/ODM. How do I solve this problem?

DCSurvey(Mysql):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Modules\DataCollection\Organisation;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;

class DCSurvey extends Model
{
    use HybridRelations;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $table = 'd_c_surveys';

    protected $fillable=['user_id','country','lang','title','category','start_date','end_date','status','istemplate','isprivate','istemporary','points','mongo_id','deleted_at'];

    public function mongosurvey(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Modules\DataCollection\MongoDB\MongoSurvey','_id','mongo_id');
    }
}
```

MongoSurvey(MongoDB):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Modules\DataCollection\MongoDB;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class MongoSurvey extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $collection = 'mongo_surveys';

    protected $casts = [
        '_id' => 'binary',
    ];

    public function dcsurvey(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Modules\DataCollection\Organisation\DCSurvey','mongo_id');
    }
}
```

app\config\database.php:

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('MONGO_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DATABASE',''),
        'username' => env('MONGO_USERNAME',''),
        'password' => env('MONGO_PASSWORD',''),
        'options'  => [
            'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'dump' => [
            'use_single_transaction',
            'dump_binary_path' =>'E:\xampp\mysql\bin',
            'timeout' => 60*5,
        ],
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

],
```

];

It Would be of great help if someone can figure this problem out. Thanks in Advance.